# C# ListView Item Image

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, foreach

How can i add a image (specified image) into listview with foreach statement
for example:

```
foreach(Video entry in videoFeed.Entries) {

listview1.items.add(entry);

listview1.items.image(imageURL);

}
```

Comment: only c sharp, express

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If what you want is to show an image for your **ListViewItem**, then you need to create an **ImageList**, fill it with images, assign the **ImageList** to the **ListView** and then tell every **ListViewItem** which image from the list to use:

```
var listView = new ListView();

// create image list and fill it 
var imageList = new ImageList();
imageList.Images.Add("itemImageKey", image);
// tell your ListView to use the new image list
listView.LargeImageList = imageList;
// add an item
var listViewItem = listView.Items.Add("Item with image");
// and tell the item which image to use
listViewItem.ImageKey = "itemImageKey";
```

You can read more about ListViewItem and how to set/use images in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or in this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ka5fex.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> adress = new List<string>()
    {
        "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-9_2351861k.jpg",
        "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-5_2351885k.jpg",
        "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-7_2351893k.jpg"
    };

    ImageList il = new ImageList();

    DownloadImagesFromWeb(address, il);

    il.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
    int count = 0;
    listView1.LargeImageList = il;
    List<string> names = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

    foreach (string s in names)
    {
        ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem();
        lst.Text = s;
        lst.ImageIndex = count++;
        listView1.Items.Add(lst);
    }
}

private void DownloadImagesFromWeb(List<string> adress, ImageList il)
{
    foreach (string img in adress)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(img);
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(respStream);
        respStream.Dispose();

        il.Images.Add(bmp);
    }
}
```

This is an option for you not to copy each image manualy to your computer, instead you provide the url and place that image in a new bitmap and add to the list.