# C# add an image (instead of text) to ListViewItem

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I'm dynamically updating a ListView like that:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = "Text1";
item.SubItems.Add("Text2");
item.SubItems.Add("Text3");
item.SubItems.Add("Text4");
item.Tag = i;
listView.Items.Add(item);
```

now I want that instead of Text4 will be a lil icon I will get dynamically from a url. I read a lot of threads and tried many things - but I can't get this to work..

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381725/c-sharp-listview-item-image

Comment: is there a reason why you aren't doing your ui with xaml?

Comment: @FredrikRedin It's probably a winform

Comment: What `View` mode do you use? Details? Here you either can use image items via an ImageList and an ImageIndex or you need to ownerdraw the ListView. This is necessary esp. if you want to display images larger than 256x256..

Comment: I don't want to display images larger than 256x256, just small icons: 16x11.
It is indeed Details.

Comment: Then simply add an ImageList with this imagesize and some color depth to the form and set it as the SmallImageList of the LV! Then each ListViewItem can have an ImageIndex which will point into that list of images.. Note that this will only work for the lvi itself, not any SubItems! These would have to be ownerdrawn..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `ImageList` in your function.
Code :

```
// get picture resource
WebClient _web = new WebClient();
byte[] _data = _wb.DownloadData("http://www.myzony.com/usr/uploads/2017/03/3197402477.png");
MemoryStream _ms = new MemoryStream(_data);
// Loaded to imagelist
ImageList list = new ImageList();
list.Images.Add("pic1",Image.FromStream(_ms));
// bind listview
listView1.SmallImageList = list;

ListViewItem _item1 = new ListViewItem();
_item1.Text = "Test";
_item1.SubItems.Add("Test2");
_item1.SubItems.Add("pic1");
_item1.ImageKey = "pic1";
listView1.Items.Add(_item1);
```

Effect Image:
[image]