# How to make list view with Images with swipe?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an array of paths to images and I need to show this images. I see that the best way is to use smth like `ListView` and set as a source my images...

I found such solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/17382282/5709159

```
public DetailImageTraceForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Text = FormTitle;


            List<string> adress = new List<string>()
            {
                "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-9_2351861k.jpg",
                "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-5_2351885k.jpg",
                "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/Jaguar-F-type-7_2351893k.jpg",
            };

            ImageList il = new ImageList();

            DownloadImagesFromWeb(adress, il);
            
            il.ImageSize = new Size(92, 92);
            int count = 0;
            Lv_images.LargeImageList = il;
            List<string> names = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

            foreach (string s in names)
            {
                ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem();
                lst.Text = s;
                lst.ImageIndex = count++;
                Lv_images.Items.Add(lst);
            }
        }


        private void DownloadImagesFromWeb(List<string> adress, ImageList il)
        {
            foreach (string img in adress)
            {
                System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(img);
                System.Net.WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
                System.IO.Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(respStream);
                respStream.Dispose();

                il.Images.Add(bmp);
            }
        }
```

But I get such result

[image]

But actually what I need is : each image need to be alone and take the full screen(container) and something like arrows on sides like left(priv) right(next) and when user click `next` arrow, so next image swipe and replace current image.

Is there such out of the box solution in winforms or not?

I know that I can put ImageBox at my container and two buttons, but I hope that there is `ListView` solution because I would like to have kind of swipe animation between images...

Comment: Nothing out of the box.  Either third party or implement it yourself (in which case, WPF would be the better option).

Comment: Adding two buttons with code alone should be even simpler in winforms than wpf..

Comment: @TaW The WPF suggestion was more focused on `I would like to have kind of swipe animation between images`

Comment: Split the question into several smaller problems and solve them one by one: how to handle swipe (gestures), how to do animations in winforms, etc.. Or find an existing control which does all that already, though that would be an off-topic question to ask for one.

Comment: You can use a custom PictureBox (for example). In its constructor, use `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);`, so the PictureBox is now selectable and accepts mouse input. Gesture are translated to mouse events. You can move your PictureBox when the screen is swiped (maybe draw a border around the PictureBox when selected to notify that is now accepting gestures). The difficult part is to handle the acceleration, there's nothing native to do that, you'll have to PInvoke if you want that effect.

Comment: Maybe [Image Viewer UserControl](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71225/Image-Viewer-UserControl) and [Image Viewer in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/image-viewer-in-C-Sharp/) to start...